# Swipe gesture starts multiple instances of same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe-gesture

I am trying to implement a tab based view wherein the user can switch between the tabs using swipe gesture. However, multiple instances of the same activity open on swipe. How can I prevent this?
Thanks

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialx=event.getX();
        initialy=event.getY();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        finalx=event.getX();
        finaly=event.getY();

        if (initialx>(finalx+150.0)){

            RadioGroup Options = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.vOptions);
            int selectedId = Options.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            final EditText QuestionNo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vnumberofquestions);
            final EditText Time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vtimeperquestion);

            if ((QuestionNo.getText().toString().equals(" ")) || (Time.getText().toString().equals("")) ||(selectedId==-1)) { 
                Intent intenta=new Intent(VerbalSelect.this, TabDisplay.class );
                intenta.putExtra("index", 0);
                startActivity(intenta);
            }
            else {   
                RadioButton selectedButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                String testtype = (String) selectedButton.getText(); 
                int questionno = Integer.parseInt(QuestionNo.getText().toString());
                int timeperquestion = Integer.parseInt(Time.getText().toString());
                long timeroffset = questionno*timeperquestion;
                Intent intent=new Intent(VerbalSelect.this, Main.class);

                intent.putExtra("testtype", testtype);
                intent.putExtra("timeroffset",timeroffset);
                intent.putExtra("questionno","1");
                intent.putExtra("questionlimit", questionno);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) in the Android support library. Most UIs of this form that you see on a stock Android device use this component.

Each page is implemented either as a `Fragment` or layout of Views instead of a full Activity. This allows for clean swiping and animation between pages and avoids the issue of multiple activities that you're having.

To supply integration with tabs you can use [`PagerTabStrip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) as provided out of the box, or for more traditional style tabs see the code examples in the Support4Demos sample included with the SDK. It can be found at `<sdk>/extras/android/compatibility/v4/samples/Support4Demos` wherever you installed the SDK. The `FragmentTabsPager` demo is what you're looking for.